# How to interactively get the coordinates of a point in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile with a single layer of type point.

It is in the Google CRS (EPSG:900913).

When I use the 'Identify Feature' tool it gives me lots of information about the point clicked on, but I can't see the coordinates. Is there a way to find out the lat/lng of a point interactively?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When using **Identify**, you can access coordinate information in the "**derived**" section of the results.

An alternative is **Coordinate Capture** plugin.

---

Update for QGIS 3.18:

In recent versions of QGIS, you can right-click in the map and select **Copy Coordinate** from the context menu

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the "Copy_Coords" plugin (add it in plugin manager).